# How to create a toggle button in Jquery-mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I want my button to change color if clicked but it seems not working in this JQuery-Mobile. and If its clicked it seems like it increases the time count speed i dont know why.
Any help please guys.

```
var seconds = 0;
var minutes = 0;
var timer = null;

function toggle(ths) {
    var clicked = $(ths).val();

    $(ths).toggleClass("btnColor");
    $("#tb").toggleClass("btnColorR");

    $("#lblType").html(clicked);
    $("#setCount").html(" minutes : " + minutes + " seconds : " + seconds);

    //duration time 
    seconds = seconds + 1;
    if (seconds % 60 == 0) {
        minutes += 1;
        seconds = 0;
    }
    timer = timer = setTimeout("toggle()", 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
 timer=setTimeout(function(){
      toogle();
 },1000);
```